# HP Presario CQ 61-322ER (VV884EA) Wi-Fi hang up!

Tags: laptop, wireless-networking, freeze

I have my new laptop and don't have Windows XP drivers for it. 
I found that it contains the Broadcom BCM4310 chip, but when I install any Broadcom
driver my laptop hangup on installing `bcm5*.sys` driver. Only power-off button 
make any effect.
After reboot the device list (Device Manager) contains Broadcom WLAN adapter, but it is marked 
as disabled, for some hardware errror!

Also if I disable device before, and install driver - then - all is OK! But when I try to enable it, Windows hang up anyway (no speaker beep, no mouse input, no keyboard input - nothing)

What is the solution?

Comment: This question should be on superuser.com

Comment: duplicate (user crossposted): http://superuser.com/questions/116841/hp-presario-cq-61-322er-vv884ea-wifi-hang-up

Answer (score 0):

HP drivers for this model for Windows XP appear to be here: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareList?os=228&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&product=4048288&lang=en. It looks like you need the HP Wireless Assistant driver.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for response. Unfortunatelly Wireless assistant - it's only GUI for managing connection. This package don't contain any drivers !